# Choosing Uk registered address for a limited company

Tags: uk, registration, virtual-office

I created one year ago a limited company. At this time, I chose to use my personal address as my "Registered Address". Now I am thinking of changing flat, so I have to change this address and I am wondering what are the best choices.

I was looking on internet a little and I see the concept of virtual office on sites like :
https://www.rapidformations.co.uk/additional-services/london-registered-office/
or
http://yourvirtualofficelondon.co.uk/registered-office-address-london/

It seems to cost around 50£/year, witch seems reasonable.

Is it a good choice? Is there other choices?

Comment: I used this for a company I recently formed: http://www.cityaddress.co.uk/
Dead cheap for £30 per year, just got my first forwarded mail from them.

Answer (score 3):

A virtual office can be useful but decide what you need it to do.

There are some very cheap solutions out there (as previously linked) and that's fine if you just want to avoid having to change business stationery and want very little else (i.e an accommodation address).

The people I use run a real business centre too. The beauty of having a virtual office with someone  is that if someone Google's you, you appear as being a business that has decent premises and get taken more seriously than if Streetview just shows residential buildings.

They also do mail handling & call handling so it's an easy way to portray yourself in a much more professional light - and saves all the hassle of changing paperwork whenever you move. Works for me.

Edited to add: I see the OP is in London so my recommendation may not work for him but of course London is full of similar business centres, as in all things I'd advise "Buy Cheap, Buy Twice" - don't go too cheap, it's false economy!